# can't install "CHAID" on Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: r, macos

I have encountered a problem of installing CHAID package on my Mac. I am not sure if it is a problem of my Mac OS version or some other problems. Could anyone help?

Thank you so much!!

> install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     unable to access index for repository http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1

package ‘CHAID’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘CHAID’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Comment: If you issue a command with a default value for "type" of "binary" and access a repository that doesn't deliver binary packages you must expect some sort of error.

Comment: thank you so much BondedDust

Answer (score 2):

You first need to install the 'partykit' package (and all of its dependincies) and then issue this command:

```
install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")
```

This is the transcript on a Yosemite machine but I think this should also succeed on Mavericks. (You can notice that there is no invocation of compiled code, so I do not need to warn you that XCode might be needed.)

```
>  install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")
Warning: dependency ‘partykit’ is not available
trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/CHAID_0.1-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 356348 bytes (347 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 347 KB

ERROR: dependency ‘partykit’ is not available for package ‘CHAID’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/CHAID’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/yq/m3j1jqtj6hq6s5mq_v0jn3s80000gp/T/RtmpMD0mfx/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("CHAID", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org",  :
  installation of package ‘CHAID’ had non-zero exit status
also installing the dependencies ‘RWekajars’, ‘pmml’, ‘strucchange’, ‘mlbench’, ‘RWeka’, ‘psychotools’, ‘psychotree’

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/RWekajars_3.7.12-1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6562134 bytes (6.3 MB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 6.3 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/pmml_1.4.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 184357 bytes (180 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 180 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/strucchange_1.5-0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 784786 bytes (766 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 766 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/mlbench_2.1-1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1021909 bytes (997 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 997 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/RWeka_0.4-24.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 533932 bytes (521 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 521 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/psychotools_0.4-0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 353913 bytes (345 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 345 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/psychotree_0.15-0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 257879 bytes (251 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 251 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/partykit_0.8-4.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1194059 bytes (1.1 MB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/yq/m3j1jqtj6hq6s5mq_v0jn3s80000gp/T//RtmpMD0mfx/downloaded_packages
> install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")
trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/CHAID_0.1-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 356348 bytes (347 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 347 KB

* installing *source* package ‘CHAID’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (CHAID)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/yq/m3j1jqtj6hq6s5mq_v0jn3s80000gp/T/RtmpMD0mfx/downloaded_packages’
>
```

Comment: XCode is the combination of compilers and development environment that Apple offers (for free). It is needed for packages that have compiled C, Fortran or C++ code.