# can't install “CHAID” on Mac OS X 10.11.1 For R Version 3.2.2

Tags: r, r-forge

Tried to follow the solution from [can't install "CHAID" on Mac OS X 10.9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248259/cant-install-chaid-on-mac-os-x-10-9-5) but it doesn't work for my case.

When I try to install the package from R-Forge and type as source, it shows following results:

```
install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/Users/guilin/Library/R/3.2/library’(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘CHAID’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

I also try to download it directly from R-forge website (CHAID_0.1-2.tar) and install it from local downloaded file, it also shows the same error.

```
package ‘~/Downloads/CHAID_0.1-2.tar’  is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

Comment: You need to post the code you used when you attempted to install from a local copy. Seems fairly likely that you made some error, but you have not posted either the code or the error transcript.

Answer (score 1):

I did have the same result to the attempt to install from r-forge. Here's what I then did (running R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"; Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit) ; i.e., "El Capitan":

In the Terminal console (following the directions on hte project webpages):

```
svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/chaid/
```

I then moved the untarred folder to my $HOME directory (which is also my working directory) and in an open R-GUI console session:

```
install.packages("partykit", dependencies=TRUE)
install.packages("~/chaid/pkg", repos=NULL, type = "source")

* installing *source* package ‘CHAID’ ...
** R
** data
snipped 20 lines of status (which suggested that the CHAID package does not require compilers)

##------ 2015-12-03 ------##
* DONE (CHAID)
```